# Container for a stack of unique elements

Tags: c++

What I'm trying to do is to construct a stack which contains unique elements.

And if an element is pushed to which is already in stack the element is not pushed but the existing elemetn should be moved to the top of the stack, i.e. 
ABCD + B > ACDB

I would like to here from you which container will be the best choice to have this functionality.

I decided to user stack adapter over list, because

1. list does provide constant time for element move
2. list is one of the natively supported containers for the stack.

The drawback of my choice is that I have to manually check for the duplicate elements.

P.S. My compiler is not so recent so please don't suggest unordered_set.

Comment: Even without a recent compiler you can still use [boost::unordered_set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/unordered_set.html) (not that it seems appropriate for this task).

Comment: Thanks for the boost solution but I would like to here smth from stl

Comment: If `unordered_set` is a possibility (apart from compiler support), why don’t you use a normal `std::set` then? However you look at it, `std::list` is the worst possible solution. Don’t even consider it. `std::vector` is going to be much more efficient.

Comment: If you really want the best solution, you should consider [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) (have a look at the [MRU list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/example/serialization.cpp) example, you may be able to adapt it to your needs).

Comment: I can't use the set because it orders internally the elements, therefore my stack order will not be kept. Why the list the worst choice ? I would like to hear some constructive explanations.

Comment: @deimus Of course. The same is true for `unordered_set` though so why mention it in your question? `list` is bad because it’s just inefficient. It has no cache locality, requires more memory than a `vector` to store the pointers between elements, and uses lots of memory allocations and indirections. Even if you needed to insert and remove in the middle, `vector` would be more efficient for 99% of applications. But you don’t even need that, you merely need addition and removal at the end, and `list` is **never** the most suitable data structure for this.

Comment: Even if you can't use `std::unordered_set` and have some weird objection to `boost::unordered_set`, you may well have either `std::tr1::unordered_set` or the ancient STL `hash_set`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: the "move" element requirement implies deletion from the middle.

Comment: @deimus: You said you only had 20 integers in a comment, maybe this should be edited in the question. Furthermore, how do you use the stack otherwise ? Do you only need the stack property once you have finish pushing, or do you pop from the stack regularly ? And what is the relative frequence of pushing/popping (if they are interleaved) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ah, I overlooked that. Doesn’t change the fact that `list` is crap, though. `vector` will *still* be faster, even for huge data.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: yes, probably, since the OP commented he only had up to 20 integers in there.

Comment: guys I switched to vector, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you have to chose between constant time moving + long search, or constant time search + long moving.

It's hard to say which would be more time-consuming, but  consider this:

- You will have to search for if the element exists *every* time you try to add an element
- You will *not* have to move elements every time, since obviously at some times you will be adding elements that are "new" for the container.

I'd suggest you to store *elements* and their *stack positions* in different containers. Store *elements* in a way that provides fast search, store *stack positions* in a way that provides fast movement. Connect both with pointers (so you can know which element is on which position, and which position holds which element <-- messy phrase, I know it!), and you will perform stuff rather fast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I like your solution. Basically the number of the elements in the stack wont be more than 20, and the elements comparision should be single comparision of ints. So I guess list is enough for this right ?

Comment: @deimus, yes, for such small amounts of data you will not see any difference is performance, so it's fine.

Comment: @deimus: for 20 integers, use `std::vector` and a linear search. It will fit in a single chunk of memory (guaranteed by vector) and thus a single line of CPU cache. It's probably the fastest solution available to you (even if the search is in theory linear).

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements, it seems to me that the structure you want could be derived from a [Max Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

If instead of storing just the item, you store a pair (generation, item), with generation coming from a monotonically increasing counter, then the "root" of the heap is always the last seen element (and the other elements do not really matter, do they ?).

- Pop: typical pop operation on the heap (`delete-max` operation)
- Push: modified operation, to account for uniqueness of "item" within the structure

  - look for "item", if found update its generation (`increase-key` operation)
  - if not, insert it (`insert` operation)

Given the number of elements (20), building the heap on a `vector` seems a natural choice.